# Jenkins - how to NOT include any external environment variables when running shell script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've found a ton of information on how to include environment variables when running jenkins shell scripts, but I need to do the opposite. I need to start with a 'fresh' environment, and set/export everything in the script(s) I'm running. Is there any way to do this in jenkins? Specifically, jenkins scripted pipeline's sh step?

Comment: There aren't many variables exposed by default: the environment is 'fresh' apart from a few required ones like PATH. Which ones are causing issues?

Comment: A good example would be RHEL devtoolsets. For compliance/security, we need to have a few different instances that are ran by individual users. The users may be exporting different versions of devtoolsets depending what software they are building - if I don't explicitly source a RHEL devtoolset, whichever one the user had set in their environment will be active in jenkins. The goal would be preventing anything but the required env vars to be included when a user starts jenkins as a safety precaution. An error would be better than building with the wrong devtoolset.

Comment: What I meant was: the environment that Jenkins provides for a job has almost nothing in it. You have to provide almost everything. Chances are, it's already what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `env -i`:

```
/usr/bin/env -i FIRST_VAR=1 SECOND_VAR=2 printenv
```

Replace `printenv` with your program.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/env